# After changing the pagination to the centre of foot, the roman pagination does not appear for front matter

Tags: lyx

I'm using `book (Memoir)` document class in `LyX`. The original format of this particular layout is having the `\frontmatter` as roman pagination and the `\mainmatter` as Arabic pagination. The page number will appear in the top left and top right for even and odd pages respectively, while the first page of each chapter will appear at the bottom centre. I am interested in changing all the pagination to bottom centre but keeping the roman and Arabic numbering.

I notice from one of the thread of the same problem that the following code can bring all the pagination to the bottom centre. So, I added the following to the Latex Preamble.

```
\makepagestyle{standard} %Make standard pagestyle

\makeatletter                 %Define standard pagestyle
\makeevenfoot{standard}{}{\thepage}{} %
\makeoddfoot{standard}{}{\thepage}{}  %
\makeevenhead{standard}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{standard}{}{}{\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{standard}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeatother                  %

\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{standard}{
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{ \quad }
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{ \quad }
\createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
\createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
\createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
\createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
\createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
\createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
   }
\makeatother                               %


\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{standard}               %Choosing pagestyle and chapter pagestyle
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}    %Change plain to standard if you want the header on pages with chapter headings
```

This can effectively bring all the pagination to the bottom centre, but, this will also make all the pagination Arabic numbering. Can any one please help to keep this position of the pagination but revert the numbering to roman for the `\frontmatter` and Arabic for the `\mainmatter`?

I have also tried `\pagenumbering{roman}` before all the frontmatter and `\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}` before the mainmatter. But the pagination are still Arabic.

Comment: I can't notice that behavior. After issuing `\mainmatter` I get arabic numbering starting from 1. Can you add a M(N)WE?

Comment: So, there is no need to use `\frontmatter`? May I know what is M(N)WE?

Comment: Take a look here: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The (N) is for "non"

Comment: I tried removing one chapter of my thesis and the roman pagination for the `\frontmatter` appeared. May I know how can a chapter affect the pagination?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the above scenario is due to a cross-reference inserted before the cross-reference label was inserted.